# shell script to backup files in a specified directory

Tags: tar

```
tar -czvf /var/local/mybackup.tar.gz -C /etc/alternatives/
```

**I used the above mentioned code to create a backup file. But it is showing me this error.**

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

**What is wrong with my code??**

Answer (score 1):

`tar` requires a list of files to include in the archive. The command

`tar -czvf /var/local/mybackup.tar.gz -C /etc/alternatives/ .`

will create a compressed tar file containing all of the files within `/etc/alternatives/`.

Comment: That star at the end of your command will be expanded by the shell in the current directory, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `-C` flag

```
$ tar czvf /path/of/the/backup/name.tar.gz /path/of/the/files
```

If you want to backup a bunch of files, use `wildcard`. If you want to backup an entire dir just do not end the line with the slash `/`

Files backup `$ tar czvf /path/to/backupdir/files.tar.gz /path/to/files/*`

Dir backup `$ tar czfP /path/to/backupdir/files.tar.gz /path/to/dir`

From `man tar`

```
-P, --absolute-names
   don't strip leading `/'s from file names
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually /etc/alternatives is entirely populated with links. Try using the -h command of tar to dereference the links they point to and include the actual files. (If that is your goal, which I assume it would be.)